# Appengine deployment failed with custom docker file

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, gcloud

I am trying to deploy my vue.js code on appengine with custom docker file but I am getting error
The docker file is working fine on my local machine. Can anyone please tell me what is the issue ?

here is my docker file

```
FROM node:9.11.1-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
# production stage
FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine as production-stage
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and this is my app.yaml

```
# application: lifeprint2-1222
service: admin-panel
env: flex
runtime: custom
network:
 forwarded_ports:
   - 80:80
# eof
```

Here are the details of error while deploying code:

```
Updating service [admin-panel] (this may take several minutes)...⠛DEBUG: Operation [apps/lifeprint2demo/operations/e858191d-28bd-4ce6-b7cc-6f6ea751ed6f] not complete. Waiting to retry.
Updating service [admin-panel] (this may take several minutes)...⠹DEBUG: Operation [apps/lifeprint2demo/operations/e858191d-28bd-4ce6-b7cc-6f6ea751ed6f] complete. Result: {
    "metadata": {
        "user": "noman.maqsood@tintash.com", 
        "target": "apps/lifeprint2demo/services/admin-panel/versions/20180902t214321", 
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1.OperationMetadataV1", 
        "insertTime": "2018-09-02T16:46:35.958Z", 
        "method": "google.appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion"
    }, 
    "done": true, 
    "name": "apps/lifeprint2demo/operations/e858191d-28bd-4ce6-b7cc-6f6ea751ed6f", 
    "error": {
        "message": "An internal error occurred during deployment.", 
        "code": 13
    }
}
Updating service [admin-panel] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                                                                        
DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred during deployment.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nomanmaqsood/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 839, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/nomanmaqsood/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 770, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/nomanmaqsood/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 90, in Run
    parallel_build=False)
  File "/Users/nomanmaqsood/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 598, in RunDeploy
    flex_image_build_option=flex_image_build_option)
  File "/Users/nomanmaqsood/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 407, in Deploy
    extra_config_settings)
  File "/Users/nomanmaqsood/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/appengine_api_client.py", line 207, in DeployService
    poller=done_poller)
  File "/Users/nomanmaqsood/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/operations_util.py", line 315, in WaitForOperation
    sleep_ms=retry_interval)
  File "/Users/nomanmaqsood/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 254, in WaitFor
    sleep_ms, _StatusUpdate)
  File "/Users/nomanmaqsood/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 316, in PollUntilDone
    sleep_ms=sleep_ms)
  File "/Users/nomanmaqsood/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 229, in RetryOnResult
    if not should_retry(result, state):
  File "/Users/nomanmaqsood/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 310, in _IsNotDone
    return not poller.IsDone(operation)
  File "/Users/nomanmaqsood/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/operations_util.py", line 184, in IsDone
    encoding.MessageToPyValue(operation.error)))
OperationError: Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred during deployment.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred during deployment.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make your container listen on port 8080 as per [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#listen_to_port_8080), you can omit the forwarded_ports part after that.

You wanting to forward 80 to 80 is colliding with the default 80 to 8080 rule.

Cheers,

Miguel.